# Can nginx cache on user-defined headers?

Tags: nginx

Let's say I have two custom headers, `foo` and `bar` that contribute to the uniqueness of a REST query, how can I configure nginx to include these in its cache key?

For example we these queries that hit the same url but should be cached differently given their headers:

```
wget --header=foo:1 --header=bar:A http://my.web.site/api/query  
wget --header=foo:1 --header=bar:B http://my.web.site/api/query
wget --header=foo:2 --header=bar:A http://my.web.site/api/query  
wget --header=foo:2 --header=bar:B http://my.web.site/api/query
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd assume adding `$http_foo` and `$http_bar` to your [`proxy_cache_key`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key) should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

nginx has configuration directive `proxy_cache_key`, which can be used to define cache key.

By default the cache key is `$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri`. By adding `$http_foo` to the key you'll get separate caching for different headers.

There is a corresponding directive for `fastcgi` too.